# Function composition and multipole expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

Assume that I have some function $g(r,\theta,\phi)$ which I have expanded in a multipole series:
$$
g(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell} g_{\ell m}(r)\, Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi).
$$
If I have scalar function $f(x)$, is there a concise way of calculating the multipole expansion of their composition $f\circ g$? That is, can I calculate
$$
f\bigl(g(r,\theta,\phi)\bigr) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell} [f\circ g]_{\ell m}(r)\, Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)
$$
in terms of $f(x)$ and $g_{\ell m}(r)$?

For a simple case like $g(r,\theta,\phi) = r + r \beta Y_{20}(\theta, \phi)$, I could think of doing something like expanding in powers of $\beta$:
$$
f\bigl(g(r,\theta,\phi)\bigr) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(r)}{k!} r^k \beta^k \bigl[Y_{20}(\theta,\phi)\bigr]^k.
$$
In this case, one would need to use the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to rewrite $\bigl[ Y_{20}(\theta,\phi) \bigr]^k$ in terms of $Y_{\ell 0}(\theta,\phi)$. Likewise, if the function $g(r,\theta,\phi)$ is basically just a scaling of $r$ (as one would have for the parameterization of a surface) such that $g(r,\theta,\phi) = r\, g(\theta,\phi)$, then I could expand around $r=0$
$$
f\bigl(r\,g(\theta,\phi)\bigr) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} r^k\left[\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell} g_{\ell m} Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi) \right]^k,
$$
where now the $g_{\ell m}$ coefficients are independent of $r$.
In this case I would need to expand arbitrary products of spherical harmonics in terms of spherical harmonics again.

Is there any more elegant or general way?